# How to rescue specific validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model with two validations for one field

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :address,
        uniqueness: {
            message: localized_message('uniqueness_key')
        },
        :format => {
            :with => /\A([a-zA-Z]\d{4}|)\z/,
            message: localized_message('format_key')
        }
```

Validation messages are localized and thus I don't know what exact text they will contain. In controller logic I need to rescue validation exception and have some specific logic for format validations.

How can I detect exactly "format" validation exception?

Comment: Which kind of formation? It depends on what you want to do, but you can always check if the instance is valid: `@my_class.valid?` and then access the errors object: `@my_class.errors`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I found was to generate my own exceptions in next way

1. Create a custom exception

   ```
    class CustomException < Exception
    end
   ```
2. Make Rails generate this exception instead of ActiveRecordException by adding **strict** property

   ```
    class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :address,
        uniqueness: {
            message: localized_message('uniqueness_key')
        },
        :format => {
            :with => /\A([a-zA-Z]\d{4}|)\z/,
            message: localized_message('format_key'),
            strict: CustomException
        }
   ```
3. In a place that I need just handle my exception

   ```
    rescue Exception => e
        if e.is_a?(CustomException)
            #Do my stuff here
        end
    end
   ```

**Update**

As @TanguyP rightly noticed in this particular implementation other exceptions which are not of `CustomException` class will be ignored and "swallowed". They should be either also handled inside `rescue Exception => e` block or thrown again in order to be handled on a higher level.

However, more correct would be to implement point 3 as follows:

3. In a place that I need just handle my exception

   ```
   rescue CustomException => e
       #Do my stuff here
   end
   ```

Comment: Why not `rescue CustomException => e`? Your code is silently ignoring `Exception`s which are not `CustomException`s.

Comment: I'd consider this as an example that skips some things in order to emphasize on a specific implementation. However, if to implement it just as it is you're right it will swallow all other exceptions and I agree with you, rescuing only  `CustomException` would be more correct. I'll update my answer I think. Thank you @TanguyP for poiting thiis issue.

Answer (score -1):

One way to get what you want is by `new`ing your object, initing it with details and then checking the object `errors`.

e.g, in your case:

```
obj = MyClass.new(address: "incorrect_address")
obj.valid?
=> false
obj.errors.messages
=>  {:address=>["format_key", "is invalid"]}
```